# Find a seven digit number which describes itself

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, puzzle

Find a seven digit number which describes itself. The first digit is the number of zeros in the number. The second digit is the number of ones in the number, etc. For example, in the number 21200, there are 2 zeros, 1 one, 2 twos, 0 threes and 0 fours.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-descriptive_number

Comment: I wonder how to generalize this: how many self-descriptive numbers are there in base b with d digits?

Answer (score 2):

$$3211000$$

$$\mathrm{                    }$$